# Collect more lists from a single stream and then merge them all

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a more elegant way collect more lists from a single stream and then merge them all?

This is what I came up with:

```
    private Set<Long> getAllIds(List<MyClass> fetchedElements) {
        Set<Long> myIds = new HashSet<>();
        myIds.addAll(fetchedItems.stream().map(MyClass::getBlueId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        myIds.addAll(fetchedItems.stream().map(MyClass::getRedId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        myIds.addAll(fetchedItems.stream().map(MyClass::getGreenId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return myIds;
    }
```

It seems to me when I look at these three lines of code as there is code duplication there, but I didn't find a way to join the different map operations I'm doing with the stream.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `flatMap`!!

```
fetchedElements.stream()
        .flatMap(item -> Stream.of(item.getBlueId(), item.getRedId(), item.getGreenId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note that the order of evaluation `BRGBRG` rather than `BBRRGG`, the output order is of course undefined as you are using a `Set`. I assume this doesn't matter.

---

You could make this method more general:

```
private Set<Long> getAllIds(List<MyClass> fetchedElements,
        List<Function<MyClass, Long>> extractors) {
    return fetchedElements.stream()
            .flatMap(item -> extractors.stream().map(f -> f.apply(item)))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Call with:

```
 Set<Long> myIds = getAllIds(fetchedElements, List.of(MyClass::getBlueId, MyClass::getRedId, MyClass::getGreenId))
```

If you want the other evaluation order, swap the order of operations:

```
extractors.stream()
    .flatMap(f -> fetchedElements.stream().map(item -> f.apply(item))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: Thanks @Boris, this is exactly what I was looking for!